# What is the Templatetype of MembersWebPart?

Tags: web-part

I would like to provision a webpart of type "MembersWebPart". What is the TemplateType number for this webpart?

Comment: Please take a look [here](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/204824/csom-add-webpart-script-editor-webpart/204827#204827), **UPD** section

Comment: Is it not possible with the TemplateType number? Or does this webpart has no TemplateType number?